# Closing connection in hiredis?

Tags: c++, redis, hiredis

How to disconnect to redis server using hiredis API?
There is API to connect but I can't find any function to close the connection?
Does `redisFree` will automatically do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

redisFree() will indeed close the connection, and deallocate memory for all attached objects.

When in doubt, you can look at the source code. It is quite easy to understand.

```
void redisFree(redisContext *c) {
    if (c->fd > 0)
        close(c->fd);
    if (c->obuf != NULL)
        sdsfree(c->obuf);
    if (c->reader != NULL)
        redisReaderFree(c->reader);
    free(c);
}
```